# How to replace all spaces within src attribute?

Tags: php, html, regex

I would like to replace all spaces within the src attribute with `%20`

Example:

```
src="//myurl.com/example string.mp3"
```

to

```
src="//myurl.com/example%20string.mp3"
```

I'm looking for a *single* RegEx selector to do this! I will be using the Wordpress [Search-Regex](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-regex/) plugin, should it be of interest.

Comment: Why not use `urlencode()`?

Comment: Because I want to change existing Wordpress posts, and I cannot use PHP functions within these

Comment: If you can't use any PHP functions at all, then this is going to be extremely difficult to do in PHP... and how can you call a Wordpress plugin if you can't use PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the fun of doing it with a regex, you can replace:

```
src\s*=\s*"[^" ]*\K\h|(?!^)\G[^" ]*\K\h
```

With `%20` (replace `"` with `'` to check single quoted strings).

**Explanation (see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/uD1lA9/1))**

The idea is to match the beginning of the `src="...` pattern, until we find a space or a quote. That way if the `\G` anchor ("end of last match") matches we know we're inside a relevant `"..."` string and we can happily match all whitespaces, until a closing `"`

```
  src\s*=\s*"   # match the opening 'src="'
  [^" ]*        # match everything until a double quote or a space
  \K            # drop out what we matched so far
  \h            # match the whitespace ('\h' is a horizontal whitespace)
|
  (?!^)\G       # match at the end of the last match (not beginning of string)
  [^" ]*\K      # match and drop until a double quote or a space
  \h            # match the whitespace
```

To keep it simple the pattern doesn't handle escaped quotes. If you need to do so you can replace the `[^" ]*` parts with `(?:\\\H|[^" \\]++)*+` (see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/uD1lA9/4))

Checking both single and double quoted strings in one pattern isn't doable this way (to my knowledge) if you can have a `'` inside a `"..."` string or vice versa (if you know that's not a worry, you can use `src\s*=\s*['"][^'" ]*\K\h|(?!^)\G[^'" ]*\K\h`, see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/uD1lA9/2)).

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that we have a string

```
var src = "//my url.com/example string .mp3"
```

the regex that will find all the spaces in the above string will be /\s/g

you can replace all spaces in javascript using

```
src = src.replace(/\s/g, '%20')
```